# Identifying JSON level with Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I want to parse a small JSON file with a nested structure. I am mainly interested in the "name" value, but as there are several name values throughout the document, it would be convenient to have a level depth identifier of some kind.

```
    {
        "status": "Tomato",
        "name": "ThisIsWhatIwant",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "THatsNoGood",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "dontlikeiteither",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Pffff",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Trump",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Obama",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Jackson5",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "NewEden": false,
        "Potatoes": []
    }
]
```

Delphi code:

```
procedure TFmain.json_extract_names(filename: string);
var jsonStr: string;
 sr: TStringReader; jtr: TJsonTextReader; s: string;
 sl: TSTringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
 jsonStr := TFile.ReadAllText(FileOpenDialog1.FileName);
 sl := Tstringlist.Create;
 sr := TStringReader.Create(jsonStr);
  try
    jtr := TJsonTextReader.Create(sr);

    try
      while jtr.Read do
      begin
        s := JsonTokenToString(jtr.TokenType);

        if jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.PropertyName then
        begin
          if jtr.Value.ToString = 'name' then
          begin
            jtr.Read;
            sl.Add(jtr.Value.AsString);
          end
          else if jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.EndObject then
          begin
            exit;
          end;
        end;

      end;
    finally
      jtr.Free;
    end;

    for I := 0 to sl.Count-1 do
     begin
       ComboBoxsearch.Items.Add(sl[i]);
     end;

  finally
    sr.Free;
    sl.Free;
  end;
End;
```

The above code works and my stringlist contains all name values - but I only need the name of the first level! Is there any way to only get the first level name? (in my example JSON the desired result would be: ThisIsWhatIwant)

Comment: Is there any good reason to be using `TJsonTextReader`? There are other ways, such as `TJsonObject` or my favorite third-party library Super Object. Honestly, I had never even heard of `TJsonTextReader` until seeing this question.

Comment: Super Object would be able to consolidate all that into just 2 lines of code: `O:= SO(MyJsonString); S:= O.S['name'];`

Comment: FWIW, `TJsonTextReader` appears to be ideal mainly for very large JSON objects, where parsing the entire thing at once would take too long. But in your case, it's rather small, so performance isn't an issue here.

Comment: @JerryDodge or, if you simply don't want to waste the overhead of allocating memory for DOM objects that will never be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TJsonTextReader` has a [`Depth`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.Readers.TJsonReader.Depth) property:

> Gets the depth of the current token in the JSON document.
>
> Depth returns an integer that represents the nested level of the current token.

For example:

```pascal
procedure TFmain.json_extract_names(filename: string);
var
  jsonStr: string;
  sr: TStringReader;
  jtr: TJsonTextReader;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  jsonStr := TFile.ReadAllText(filename);
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sr := TStringReader.Create(jsonStr);
    try
      jtr := TJsonTextReader.Create(sr);
      try
        while jtr.Read do
        begin
          if (jtr.Depth = 1) and
             (jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.PropertyName) and
             (jtr.Value.ToString = 'name') then
          begin
            jtr.Read;
            sl.Add(jtr.Value.AsString);
          end;
        end;
      finally
        jtr.Free;
      end;
    finally
      sr.Free;
    end;
    ComboBoxsearch.Items.AddStrings(sl);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
End;
```

Comment: Many thanks Remy, I was indeed looking for any property indicating the depth/level! Thank you so much.